# Class <classname> : Expression is too long, please split this expression into multiple statements

Tags: apex, compile-error

I have never seen this error before. It comes up when trying to run a test in Production. It happens when promoting the class (with just some capitalization changed, so it's not a real change) to Production. Class is running in API 49.0 and compiles fine in a full sandbox on Summer20 (49.0) and in a partial sandbox running Winter21 (50.0), and it fails in Production running Winter21 (50.0).

The error has no line number, and it shows when deploying using change set and via Gearset.

When trying to compile all classes (the link on the Apex class list) it gives one of those "provide this error code to Salesforce" pages. Not very helpful!

This started right after the org was updated to Winter21. Our nightly test run came back with an error. We hadn't edited the code at all.

Has anyone ever seen this error? A Google search for the error text yields nothing.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code? Or, if you want, you can send it to me directly, I'd be glad to review it for you (as you may know, I'm really good at debugging).

Comment: I have seen it. If you have a string which is too long, like ```String a = '1' + '2'+ ... '100000000'; ``` it will fail with this error. Solution like ```String a = '1' + '2' + ... '50000000'; a+= ('50000001' + ... + '100000000'); ``` solved the problem

Comment: In my case it was occurring on test class mock string variable definition to mock a huge response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, all.

The error "magically" went away. I can now compile all classes and can promote the class to production without any problems.

I dislike intermittent problems. Salesforce has been notified and is doing testing on a similar issue that came in to them at the same time.

EDIT: The bug has been fixed by Salesforce.

Comment: Looks like a known issue has since been created: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003wdVQAQ
It is affecting me too intermittently, and if I re-try without changing anything, sometimes the error goes away and it works